Placing multiple Coordinate Systems in one Image
I want to visualize two coordinate systems in one image.
Minimal working example:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  view={35}{15},
  axis lines=center,
  width=15cm,height=15cm,
  xtick={-1,1},ytick={-1,1},ztick={-1,1},
  xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3,zmin=-3,zmax=3,
  xlabel={$x$-axis},ylabel={$z$-axis},zlabel={$y$-axis},
]

% plot dots for the two points
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,2,0)};
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,0,0)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


In this plot, how can I draw a second coordinate system at the point (0, 0, 2)? The coordinate system should have differently scaled axes, and its visualization should be a bit smaller, so the image does not get too big.
Edit: You may notice that I switched the labels of the y- and z-axes. This is done on purpose, and I want to place the second coordinate system on the axis labeled z-axis.

You can use the view option to rotate your coordinate system and z dir=reverse to reverse the direction of the z-axis if you really really want a left turned coordinate system (I hope you did this by a mistake). Naming the axis with something that they are not can and will cause confusion. It is probably already a problem in the answer you got.

No, the labels are correct. I was not able to rotate the z-axis by 90 degrees, so I just changed the labels. Which parameters for view did you use to rotate the z-axis? Whenever I tried changing the view, the z-axis remained unchanged and the x- and y-axes adapted.

You are correct(you can not change the z-axis with view). You need to use e.g. the x, y and z options to set the unit vectors of your coordinate system.  E.g. y={(0cm,1cm)}

I posted a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/724535/shifting-origin-of-coordinate-systems-with-custom-axes

You can put two axis environments into one tikzpicture, and use shift to change the origin.  Note that (A) and (B) must be created inside the first axis environment in order to use the local (axis cs:) coordinate system, but the difference must be computed outside.  This appears to be a bug in calc.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
  view={35}{15},
  axis lines=center,
  width=15cm,height=15cm,
  xtick={-1,1},ytick={-1,1},ztick={-1,1},
  xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3,zmin=-3,zmax=3,
  xlabel={$x$-axis},ylabel={$z$-axis},zlabel={$y$-axis},
]

% plot dots for the two points
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,2,0)};
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,0,0)};

\coordinate (A) at (axis cs: 0,2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs: 0,0,0);
\coordinate (C) at ($(A)-(B)$);% incorrect result
\end{axis}

\draw[red] (B) -- ++(C);% demo only

\begin{axis}[shift=($(A)-(B)$),
  scale only axis,
  view={35}{15},
  axis lines=center,
  width=15cm,height=15cm,
  xtick={-1,1},ytick={-1,1},ztick={-1,1},
  xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3,zmin=-3,zmax=3,
  xlabel={$x$-axis},ylabel={$z$-axis},zlabel={$y$-axis},
]

% plot dots for the two points
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,2,0)};
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,0,0)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


For axis lines=center the origin (0,0,0) is located at (7.5cm,7.5cm) for a width and height of 15cm.  (Including length units forces pgfplots to use the screen coordinates instead of axis cs:.)  This does not appear to be affected by the view angle or other parameters.  This means one can compensate for changes in the width and height between axis environments
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
  %axis equal,
  view={35}{15},
  axis lines=center,
  width=15cm,height=15cm,
  xtick={-1,1},ytick={-1,1},ztick={-1,1},
  xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3,zmin=-3,zmax=3,
  xlabel={$x$-axis},ylabel={$z$-axis},zlabel={$y$-axis},
]

% plot dots for the two points
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,2,0)};
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,0,0)};

\coordinate (A) at (axis cs: 0,2,0);% new origin location
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs: 0,0,0);
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[shift={($(A)-(B)+(2.5cm,2.5cm)$)},
  scale only axis,
  %axis equal,
  view={35}{15},
  axis lines=center,
  width=10cm,height=10cm,
  xtick={-1,1},ytick={-1,1},ztick={-1,1},
  xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2,zmin=-2,zmax=2,
  xlabel={$x$-axis},ylabel={$z$-axis},zlabel={$y$-axis},
]
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Thanks for the answer! Sorry I am a complete beginner to 3d drawing, in which coordinate system is the point A given? I tried the coordinates (100,1,3), which has no positioned the second coordinate system in the respective coordinates of the first coordinate system. Your answer also produces an offset in the y-axis and not in the z-axis.

You labeled the z-axis as y-axis and vice verses.  The z axis is always up (or down) for any view angle.

Yes, I relabeled the z- and y-axes because the pgf z-axis always points up. However, I see no simple method of changing the position of the second coordinate system in your solution accordingly.

The z-axis direction can be changed with e.g. x={(1.1cm,-0.2cm)}, y={(0cm,1cm)}, z={(-0.9cm,-0.3cm)}, (Use z dir=reverse for a left turned coordinate system if it is absolutely needed) . This is by far not optimal as it needs manual adjustments, but it is the best solution I can see.

You are right, I violated the axes naming conventions. I posted a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/724535/shifting-origin-of-coordinate-systems-with-custom-axes. Maybe you can answer it too ;)

Thanks for the coordinates, they are better then the coordinates I found.

Eeek!  It turns out that the shift is much more complicated than I first thought (not really knowing what to expect).

This only works by chance because the two coordinate systems are the same size - any size difference - even just some labels sticking out will ruin it. Think of (A), (B) and ($(A)-(B)$) as a vectors instead of fixed points when using shift. You are shifting the anchor point(lower left corner) by this vector.

@JohnKormylo: not really.
