Shifting Origin of Coordinate Systems with Custom Axes
I want to draw a second coordinate system at position (0,0,2).
Here is my code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  x={(1.1cm,-0.2cm)},
  y={(0cm,1cm)},
  z={(-0.9cm,-0.3cm)},
  axis lines=center,
  width=15cm,height=15cm,
  xtick={-1,1},ytick={-1,1},ztick={-1,1},
  xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3,zmin=-3,zmax=3,
  xlabel={$x$-axis},ylabel={$y$-axis},zlabel={$z$-axis},
]

% plot dots for the two points
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,0,2)};
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,0,0)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Notice that I am not using the default axes.
Thanks in advance!

PGFPlots version 1.8 is terrible old and will cause a lot of problems. -update your LaTeX.

width=15cm,height=15cm, does not make sense and is ignored, when you use explicit axis units.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x={(1.1cm,-0.2cm)}, y={(0cm,1cm)}, z={(-0.9cm,-0.3cm)},
axis lines=center,
xtick={-1,1}, ytick={-1,1}, ztick={-1,1},
xmin=-3, xmax=3,
ymin=-3, ymax=3,
zmin=-3, zmax=3,
xlabel={$x$-axis},ylabel={$y$-axis},zlabel={$z$-axis},
]
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,0,2)};
\addplot3 [only marks] coordinates {(0,0,0)};
\coordinate (A) at (0,0,2);
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
at=(A), anchor=origin,
x={(1.1cm,-0.2cm)}, y={(0cm,1cm)}, z={(-0.9cm,-0.3cm)},
axis lines=center,
ticks=none,
xmin=-0.8, xmax=0.8,
ymin=-0.8, ymax=0.8,
zmin=-0.8, zmax=0.8,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks a lot, that is what I imagined when I wrote my first question.
